How can I make the edge geometry fully join?
I want to convert edges into steel frames and ensure they are connected. On the left is a default cube with Geometry Nodes - the problem is that the new geometry of beams/edges doesn't fully join like the right cube. The vertices have a "gap" I wish to close. What must I do?

Here's an updated version of the node setup and its Blender file. Note that it creates the beams a little bigger because the cubes are added from their center.


Result:

This new solution is lighter. It adds way less geometry to the edges, only the joints instead of the hundreds of new cubes. The only downside is that it doesn't look too good on non-rectilinear angles.

I still have one issue. The total dimensions are different before and after the geometry nodes. Because the instances cubes are inserted by the middle of their x,y,z coordinates. Here`s a follow up: How to make instanced primitives' max/min coordinates to not be higher/lower than input mesh? (geometry nodes)

This may involve creating  joints at the ends of your curves.. are your junctions always rectilinear?

As @RobinBetts says, this would need more work. The problem is, a curve cannot branch, i.e. not split in two or more directions from a control point. That's why the corners are disconnected (actually, the horizontal ones in tthe center are not all connected either, it is just not so obvious. Joining those points could only be done with vertices of a mesh, but than you cannot use the Curve to Mesh node to give them a profile. If your corners were always orthogonal like in the exmaple, you could for example instance cubes there to fill the gaps.

Could this approach suite your need : How can I create a procedural "vent" mesh? ? (using just the inner tube)

@RobinBetts they'll always be rectilinear. Thank you guys, i'm still learning geometry nodes.

another approach for the perpendicular shapes



May I suggest to add a Merge by Distance node after the Join Geometry node to "glue" corners and bars?

I've reached a solution. It works even for asymmetrical and angular meshes. In this case, you need to adjust the Curve to Point node count to a high number. I've set around 500. If the mesh is rectilinear, then a lower amount works just fine.


May I ask why is the purpose of the bottom right Join Geometry and Curve to Mesh nodes ?

@StefLAncien It's not relevant to the GN setup. Thanks for pointing out. I had lots of different sources, attempts and even ChatGPT help. Linking instance on points output directly to set shade smooth's geometry input works.
