How to make instanced primitives' max/min coordinates to not be higher/lower than input mesh? (geometry nodes)
The goal here is to not let each instanced cube's position to go beyond the input mesh'.
The cube primitive node is added as instances into points of the input mesh. However, the cubes are placed from their center. D'd like to pull them inside, not letting them to be placed outside the input mesh. The idea was getting the input mesh's bounding box and use it to limit each instance individually with translate instances... but i'm not being able to do it.


In your case all you need is simple maths to shrink the spawning geometry:



Thank you for the help. Awesome solution! I just had trouble connecting your setup to the Group Input node. I'd love to apply the g. nodes on different meshes

This won't work on non-cubes. If you prepare some examples of meshes maybe we can figure something more generalized...

The goal here is quickly prototyping steel frames(and learning more about g. nodes in the process). Ty so much. I've posted a new answer on the other topic with photos of nodes, results and Blender file: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/319617/geometry-nodes-how-to-make-the-edge-geometry-to-fully-join-almost-there/319843#319843
